# Use react router to save also a page state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

It's my first time I use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) and I have some doubts.
My web page is composed by a homepage and other pages containing an accordion. Each of these pages have the same structure, what change is the item of the accordion based on some data.

[Here the working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-2j0hs).

As you can see, Homepage contains 3 buttons, if you click on one of them, the web app goes to `/[title]`, that page contains a menu and the accordion. The default open accordion item is the first one.

Ok, that works. My problem now is that if you click on a button of the menu in the /[title] page, you go to another page but the open accordion item is the same as the previous.

Example:

- Homepage: click on `tomato`
- App goes to /tomato, the open accordion item is `section 0`
- Click on section 2 -> section 0 will close and section 2 will open
- Click on `blue`, app goes to /blue the open accordion item is `section 2` and not `section 0`!

I think I can save in a global state the open accordion index and reset it to 0 when user clicks on a menu button but I'm asking if there is a way to save the index in the url like for example:

`/[title]/[index]` or `/[title]#[index]`

and use it like a state, so make it always updated.

I didn't know how to do that. I read the documentation but I can't find something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* persist the active section for each page in state somewhere, but IMO there's a simpler way. Add the `key` prop from the route to the `Page` component so when the route path changes you can signal to React to remount the `Page` component, thereby resetting it to select the first accordion section.

```
{dataset.map((page) => (
  <Route
    key={page.title}
    path={page.title}
    element={<Page key={page.title} page={page} activeSub={0} />}
  />
))}
```

[image: Edit use-react-router-to-save-also-a-page-state]